# Vue 2 - Import on demand

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue.js, webpack-2

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import { 
         Button, 
         Select,
         Table,
         Form, 
        } from 'element-ui'


import App from './App.vue'

Vue.component(Button.name, Button)
Vue.component(Select.name, Select)

// Used by admin section of the website
Vue.component(Table.name, Table)
Vue.component(Form.name, Form)

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/admin', meta: { requiresAuth: true }, component: Admin},
];

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

I am using the components Button and Select for everyone, but I'm using the Table and Form ones only for the admin page. 
The admin section is a Vue component that includes others components.

Here is the question. Since I want to optimize the size of the bundle build by Webpack, how could I import import Button and Select by default, but Table and Form just if you reach the admin section ?

I guess I would need to have more than one chunk in Webpack but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just missed that in the Vue Router documentation

```
const Foo = resolve => {
  // require.ensure is Webpack's special syntax for a code-split point.
  require.ensure(['./Foo.vue'], () => {
    resolve(require('./Foo.vue'))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you'll need to separate your file into several ones. You should take a look at [single files component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

This way you'll be able to manage your dependencies in a component level.

And if you feel more confortable with tolls tha auto-configure (almost) everything for you, [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) is the tool you need.

Comment: I am actually using single file component structure, but the bundle generated with Webpack generates only one app.js which is loaded at the begining. This file contains component that are only used in the admin section and I would like to avoid that

Comment: So, instead of creating your component in your main file, you should import them like `import Table from 'path/toTable`, this way you'll be able to manage your dependencies.

Comment: I did it but now even if the import are locals my bundle size does not change. I would like to import Admin from './components/admin/Admin.vue' only if I am the administrator and not a normal user

Comment: Maybe this will solve your problem > https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-require/